# Angular detectar cambio variable

Tags: angular

tengo 2 componentes que se pintan a la vez

componente 1 html

```
<p>hola</p>
<button (click)="despedir()">Despedida</button>
```

componente 2 html con variable mostrar a false

```
<div *ngIf="mostrar">
<p>Adios</p>
</div>
```

y en el componente 1 en la funcion despedir cambio mostrar a true, pero no soy capaz de que reciba el cambio el componente 2

Comment: Cuál es la relación entre componente 1 y 2, ¿cómo están conectados?

Comment: ninguna solo con un servicio, es una pagina dnd se pintan los 2 componentes y lo k kiero es k se muestre el componente 2 cuando pulso el boton del componente 1

Comment: ¿Pero estás seguro de que cuando llamas a `despedir` estás cambiando la variable `mostrar` del componente 2? Porque a simple vista, sin más detalles, diría que lo que estás haciendo es cambiar una variable `mostrar` del mismo componente 1. Probablemente deberías hacerlo a través del servicio. O si no, buscar otro método para guardar el estado de la aplicación

Comment: en el servicio tengo una variable mostrar inicializada a false y en los ngOnInit de ambos componentes obtengo el valor de esa variable con una funcion del servicio (false para ambos componente), y cuando doy al boton del componente 1 cambio la variable del servicio a true, pro no me lo detecta el componente 2 para mostrarme su mensaje

Comment: Es necesario que agregues la parte del código en donde usas el componente 1 y 2, para ver la forma en la que cambias el valor y como tienes definidos cada uno de estos en el componente principal. ;)

Comment: Sube más código, donde aparecen estos dos componentes. Sino no podremos ayudarte

Comment: @Kargate creo también que puedes utilizar un ViewChild en adición a la respuesta True Alex Cv me corrigen si se pueda hacer!

Comment: [Esto](https://medium.com/angular-chile/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-componentes-explicado-con-dragon-ball-z-angular-7-parte-2-5403ec132718) puede interesarte, el uso de Observables es la forma que a mi parecer deberías usar, **BehaviorSubject** te ayudaría mucho en este caso. ;)

Comment: A tu componente 2 implementa [OnChanges](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) es parte del `lifecycle` de un componente, en el metodo `ngOnChanges(changes)` haces un `if` donde valides tu @Input() `if(changes['entrada'] != null && changes['entrada'].currentValue)` si es `true` dentro de tu `if` en `changes['entrada'].currentValue` obtendras el valor mandado del componente 1. aca un [Ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hbm8xr?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

Para ello te recomiendo que uses los `@Input` y `@Output` de Angular:

En el componente 2:

```
@Input() mostrar2: boolean;
```

En la etiqueta que cargas el componente 2 le pasas la variable `mostrar` del componente 1:

```
<componente2 [mostrar2]="mostrar"></componente2>
```

Comment: lo he probado pro ocurre lo mismo, no me detecta el cambio

Comment: He leido tu otra respuesta, debes tener algun error con los servicios. Lo mejor es que la función despedida cambie una variable mostrar de dicho componente a true. @Kargate

Comment: pro si cambio una variable del mismo componente a true no influye en el componente 2 para k se muestre

Comment: @Kargate Para eso están los inputs, al cambiar la variable de ese componente a true, el otro componente recibe el valor true de dicha variable y se le asigna a la suya

Comment: @Kargate Prueba con lo que te he dicho sin usar servicios. Si quieres hacerlo con servicios tienes que usar Observable

Comment: con los input y output no me sale, como seria con observables??

Comment: @Kargate Pues importa import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; y la función ponla asi:
nombreFunction(parametros): Observable<any> { codigo }

Answer (score 0):

tengo esta pagina

```
<componente1></componente1>
<componente2></componente2>
```

la componente1 es

```
<p>hola</p>
<button (click)="despedir()">Despedida</button>
```

componente 2 html con variable mostrar a false

```
<div *ngIf="mostrar">
<p>Adios</p>
</div>
```

typescrypt componente 1

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   
}
despedir(){
 this.servicio.setMostrar(false);
}
```

typescrypt componente 2

```
mostrar = this.service.getMostrar();
ngOnInit(): void {
}
```

servicio

```
mostrar = false;
getMostrar(): boolean{
return this.mostrar;
}
setMostrar(dato){
this.mostrar=dato;
}
```

las paginas es lo primero k se pinta x lo k se inicializa el mostrar a false, pro cuando le doy al boton del componente 1 no me detecta k ha cambiado el valor en el componente 2

Comment: Hola @Kargate esto lo debes colocar en tu pregunta inicial, no debe estar como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con mobx,

```
import { makeObservable, action, observable }   from 'mobx'

    constructor () {
            makeObservable(this, {
                variable_que_quieres_observar: observable,
                           .....
    funcion_que_modifica_tu_variable: action,
                
            })
        }
```

Y por ultimo observas a tu componente

```
observer(App);
```

Comment: no entiendon esta forma k es observer(App) y no me pilla el mobx